# Run command if window is fullscreen?

Tags: xorg, compiz, window-manager

Is there any way to run a pre-set command everytime any window goes fullscreen?
I want to run unclutter whenever an application goes fullscreen and close it when the app leaves fullscreen. I tried devilspie, but it can't match properties like size.

Edit: Or, is there any other way to auto-hide the cursor for *every* fullscreen window, regardless of the application?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly want you are trying to achieve but do you manually make the window full screen? like with the F11 key? 
If so, you could map a shortcut for that key to execute a small script, so every time you press it it makes the window full screen and also runs a command you want.

Comment: No, that doesn't do it. I want to hide the cursor regardless of what triggered the fullscreen window or which application it belongs to.